# SSIS Dynamic file name save for later use

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 \ SQL SSIS.

I have a package that exports a file and dynamically names with a datetime stamp using a variable.  For example the file will be called 'Test_20190725_153932.csv'

Is there a way to store this filename somewhere without using a loop to retrieve the filename?  The variable creating the file is dynamic, so obviously it changes each time it is called.  I want to store the actual file name for a later down in the SSIS package.

Thanks.

Comment: Use an expression task to create the (dynamic) file name and store it to a variable. Then reference that variable instead for the remainder of the package.

Comment: I'm creating the file using an Expression within a variable, how do I retrieve this later in the pipeline though?  If I call the variable, the filename will have changed as the datetime stamp includes seconds.

Comment: How will the value of the variable have changed unless you change it? Don't change it after you've set it and there's not a problem.

Comment: @Larnu ah ok.  I was under the impression that if I called the same variable later on its like when you click on 'Evaluate Expression' in Expression Builder - it keeps changing every time I click it

Comment: A variable defined by an expression will have the expression derived every time you reference it (just like a computed column in a table); hence why you need to use an **expression task**.

Comment: You could also consider an expression on a precedence constraint. I have used that approach. But also you might need to put in a "dummy" step if this is the first logical operation. But you can then also use the constraint to drive additional logic. Something to consider.

Comment: As Larnu mentioned you can use an [Expression Task](https://chrisalbrektson.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/ssis-expression-task/) to achieve that